# Yodlee Aggregation REST API containerNames

Tags: yodlee

The call to getSiteInfo returns, among other things, a list of enableContainers.

Each of these is a hash eg: { "containerName":"bills", "assetType":0 }

1. Is there an exhaustive list of containerNames?
2. Is there an exhaustive list of assetTypes and what do the enums mean?

I have looked through the Yodlee developer's docco but can't find the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things to know about this.

1. This enabled containers varies depending upon which all containers are enabled for you as a customer, for example if you are interested only in bank and credit cards then this can be configured and irrespective of what other container types Yodlee supports you will get only these two container types.
2. Exhaustive list- bank, credits(for credit cards), loan/mortgage, bills(can have- minutes,telephone,utilities,cable_satellite,bills), insurance, stocks(for investments), miles(for Rewards) and prepay.

**Asset Types**- can be of 0,1,2 where all you containers which will have your asset will get 1, containers considered as liabilities will have this value as 2 and rest will have 0.